# How to fetch results from CoreData in a segue

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit, nsfetchedresultscontroller, segue

I have an iOS app using CoreData and Restkit 0.20.  The main view controller is a collection view that is populated by a request to my server using Restkit.  The request to the server returns an image and title to be placed in each cell.  If a user selects a cell I need to make a second request to the server for the details about the chosen cell.

I have spent the evening attempting to accomplish this in the `prepareForSegue` method.  The problem is I can't seem to figure out how to get the results from the request that takes place in `prepareForSegue`.

Here is the `prepareForSegue` method

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"newsDetail"]) {

// I USE THIS PORTION TO GET DATA THAT IS NEEDED FOR THE GET REQUEST TO THE SERVER AND TO PASS SOME ADDITIONAL ITEMS FROM THE FIRST REQUEST TO THE DETAIL VIEW CONTROLLER
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [[self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems] lastObject];
        NSManagedObject *object = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        NSString *articleID =[object valueForKey:@"gistID"];
        NSString *personID = [object valueForKey:@"userID"];

// I USE THIS LINE TO ASSEMBLE THE STRING FOR getObjectsAtPath BELOW
        NSString *getArticle =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/rest/article/getArticleForView?aid=%@&pid=%@&ip=255.255.255.0",articleID,personID];

//HERE I MAKE THE CALL TO THE SERVER USING RESTKIT METHODS        
        [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPath:getArticle parameters:nil success:nil failure:nil];    

        [[segue destinationViewController] setDetailItem:object];
    }
}
```

Here is how I load it in the detail view controller.

```
- (void)configureView
{
    if (self.detailItem) {
        self.newsDetailText.text = [[self.detailItem valueForKey:@"fullArticle"]description];
        NSURL *photoURL =[NSURL URLWithString:[self.detailItem valueForKey:@"imageUrl"]];
        NSData *photoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:photoURL];
        self.newsDetailImageView.image =[UIImage imageWithData:photoData];
    }
}
```

It will segue properly and the image (which was already persisted from the first request) will be loaded but the text (which was retrieved from the request at segue) will not.  In fact the `valueForKey` `fullArticle` is null.

It's probably pretty obvious I'm a rookie based on the question.  With that in mind code snippets are VERY helpful.  Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't loading the data inside the destination view controller and handling the success and error callbacks so you know what happened?

Comment: Wain, Mostly becuase I'm pretty new at this and am still learning the best ways to handle these things.  Are you suggesting I make the call to the server in the viewDidLoad portion of the detail view controller and load everything from there?  If so I had considered that but thought it will be easier to perform the operation in the segue. I figured the main viewcontroller has all the necassary components to make the call and just pass the findings into the detail viewcontroller.  I am open to suggestions though! If you see a better way I'll give it a shot.

Comment: I'd do something more like pass the path to the destination view controller and allow it to start the download and handle the response data + callbacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are doing an asynchronous request, the data you wanna show are being arrived after the `destinationViewController` actually appeared. So, you should pass a `success` block to your request and update your view inside it. Something like this:

```
UIViewController *viewController = [segue destinationViewController];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPath:getArticle parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
    if (!operation.error) {
        viewController.newsDetailText.text = mappingResult.firstObject[@"fullArticle"];
    }
} failure:nil];
```

Comment: leo, just gave your suggestion a try.  logic make sense but I'm getting this error `-[NSManagedObject objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x854ba60`  It occurs on the `viewController.newsDetailText.text` line.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Ben, thanks for considering it. I actually didn't implement this code, just wrote it by following the RestKit documentation. Based on the error you are getting, there's something wrong with `mappingResult.firstObject[@"fullArticle"]`. Try to inspect how is your data available from `mappingResult`. Here's the [documentation](http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKMappingResult.html) for this class.

Comment: Leo, I looked over the documentation and I'm not sure I can utilize your suggestion I appreciate your efforts though.  I have moved away from performing this in the segue to what wain has suggested above.  I still run into the same lack of knowledge though.  I just can't seem to figure out how to utilize the `fetchedResultsController` to perform a fetch on the object I just acquired from the server.

Comment: Did you tried this? `NSError *error = nil;
id _id = @(1234);
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:NSStringFromClass([NSManagedObject class])];
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.id == %@", _id];
[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];`

Comment: I hadn't yet because I was using the `fetchedResultsController` method that handles all those steps.  I had studied those exact lines in the apple developer library but hadn't committed to trying that yet.  I pasted it into my code.  Now I'm not sure what the NSPredicate function serves.  The code throws an exception at that line.  Currently working on it.

Comment: The `NSPredicate` is basically used to filter your data. You can filter fetch results and even `NSArray`s with it. Just type on the format string the condition you wanna satisfy, in your case an unique identifier for the record. You can also use it with blocks.

Comment: leo, you were exactly right with your first response.  I just had to change one line of your response to get it to work!  Thanks for all the help!